# Why does the 'hand of the king' symbol show a left hand?

Tags: game-of-thrones

**The right hand** often appears as [a metaphor in the bible or as a motif in art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_hand_of_God) so it would make more sense if the pin shows the right hand.

[image: image of the pin]
[image: image of the symbol]

Comment: Swords are used with right-hand? So hand-of-the-king is for shield?

Comment: Maybe it's meant to represent the king's literal right hand anointing his deputy.

Comment: Ah, the palm detail clearly shows a left hand.

Comment: Perhaps it's stage-left

Comment: "To his oldest supporters he gave new honors. Daemon Velaryon, Lord of the Tides, was made master of ships, in command of the royal fleet. Triston Massey, Lord of Stonedance, was named master of laws, Crispian Celtigar master of coin. And Orys Baratheon he proclaimed to be "**my shield, my stalwart, my strong right hand**." Thus Baratheon is reckoned by the maesters the first King's Hand."

Comment: In Jewish traditions, the left hand is literally called "The hand of the King"; https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Tales_of_Rabbi_Nachman/12#[The_King_and_the_Hand]

Comment: The right hand is holding a to-go coffee.

Comment: Hmm... In many cultures, the left hand is considered unclean and used for wiping one's behind... What did Jaime say back in season one, about what the "honour" of being the king's hand really means? "The King shits, and the Hand wipes"?

Comment: If the *hand of the King* is the left does that leave the right hand for the Kings Guard as your 'right hand man' would be the strength and protector?

Comment: What do you want to bet it's because the artist that made the pin is right handed, and was using their left hand as a reference?

Comment: I would look a bit odd as the badge is worn on the left breast so a right hand there would look strange.?

Comment: Would you please explain why you reference the bible as part of your reasoning? The bible is not part of the Game of Thrones in any way, correct? If we are able to reference other works, then I have many I would like to share other than the bible.

Comment: @Kai No reference, but I'd bet you're correct!

Comment: According to the GOT wiki, each hand is free to design his own symbol - as long as it contains a hand in it. I think it's left open to interpretation as to why its a left hand instead  of right. Funnily enough, I find @user56reinstatemonica8 's reason for why the left hand is used to be a pretty plausible one ("The King shits, the Hand wipes").

Comment: I haven't seen the TV series but in the book, Mace Tyrell is hand of the king at the end of A Dance with Dragons, and he sits in a wooden throne in the shape of a hand. I don't think it was mentioned which hand it was though.

Answer (score -1):

People have always been predominately right-handed, and the right hand is generally the sword-holding hand, i.e the 'protector', while the left hand generally means the heart.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence that the "hand of the king" relates to the heart?  The intention is to provide an answer that makes sense in-universe.

Comment: While this may be true, how does it explain why the left hand was chosen for GoT's symbol?

Comment: The left hand, in the bible symbolises punishment and Justice while the right blessings and mercy. The kings hand is in charge of punishment and Justice.